# Chrome dev-tools crashes when debugging iframe contentWindow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug an iframe's `contentWindow`, but every time i try to view the `contentWindow` object on **chrome 59** `dev-tools` the page crashes.

It happens when hovering the `contentWindow` property on breakpoint or when clicking on the console logged object.

I'm using ReactJS so i created a react fiddle although i don't think that's relevant.

[Fiddle to reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/92026/):

1. Open the dev-tools
2. Click "Try-it"
3. Click the `console.logged` object.

Is there a way to avoid the crash?

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Canary. I'm trying to find a bug on the tracker about it but not found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed on chrome 60 thanks to the new [context selection](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#context). feature